# GET /login 302 5.603ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

im making a login for Discord but im getting a 302 code error
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PklR7.png) my login code is:

```js
 app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${
        process.env.bot_id
      }&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
        process.env.bot_redirect
      )}&response_type=code&scope=${encodeURIComponent(
        ["identify", "guilds"].join(" ")
      )}`)
  });

  app.get("/auth/callback", passport.authenticate("discord"), (req, res) => {})

  bindAuth(app, client)

function bindAuth(app, client) {
  app.use(session({store: new SQLiteStore(), secret: "ChatGlobalAPI", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false}))

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
  })

  passport.use(
    new Strategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.bot_id,
        clientSecret: process.env.bot_secret,
        callbackURL: process.env.bot_redirect,
        scope: ["identify", "guilds"]
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
          profile.tokens = { accessToken }
          return done(null, profile)
        })
      }
    )
  )
    }
```

This is the first time this happens, i tried to search in google and here, in stackoverflow but i dont get an answer, i tried all but nothing.

Comment: [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is a temporary redirect, not an error

Comment: what? uh i dont understand you

Comment: Click on the link in my comment.

Comment: No, it means that the resource was temporarily moved and the new address is in the `Location` header. You have to send the same request to the new address.

Comment: Ok and why it sais its moved, how can i send the same request to the new adress, any docs?

Comment: Your code creates this redirect: `res.redirect(\`https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${process.env.bot_id}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(process.env.bot_redirect)}&response_type=code&scope=${encodeURIComponent(["identify", "guilds"].join(" "))}\`)` https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect